# Pattern search in pandas.dataframe.query()

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching

I have the following dataframe:

```
----------------------------
Index| col1 | col2 |
----------------------------
0    | 1    | a-b-c

1    | 2    | d-e-f

2    | 3    |  g
----------------------------
```

I want to be able to make queries like:

```
myvar= 'a'
df.query('@myvar in col2')
```

But it always work for exact match. Is there any solution for pattern match?

Thanks,

Rtut

Comment: i'm afraid you can't do it using `.query()`. It will compare your `@myvar` to the whole string - try to set `myvar = "g"` and re-execute your query - it'll return you a row with `index == 2`...

Comment: Hi Max Does python regular expressions work for .query() or do you have any other solution to make it work with .query() function?

Answer (score 6):

A bit overkill for what the OP needs but this post shows up first in search results for regex matching in `df.query()` which can be done with [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```py
df.query("some_str_col.str.match('some-regex-\\d+$')")
```

You may have to first convert the dtype of the column to string:

```py
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
myvar = 'a'
df.query('col2.str.contains(@myvar)')
```

Comment: This would only work with the query's pythonic engine, so you should add `engine='python'` to the `query` method.  That's what I found from this [pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8749).

Comment: @petobens Acording to the most recent [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), the engine "tries to use numexpr, falls back to python", so explicitly using `engine='python'` isn't necessary, although it could speed things up a little if you know that the query string will always use python `str` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a-b-c'], [2, 'd-e-f'], [3, 'g']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

myvar = 'a'

df.loc[df.col2.str.contains(myvar)]

   col1   col2
0     1  a-b-c
```

Comment: Why query() function has this limitation? I can not use the method that you have suggested because my query string is dynamically generated by user.

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid you can't do it using .query(). It will compare your @myvar to the whole string - try to set myvar = "g" and re-execute your query - it'll return you a row with index == 2.

AFAIK, regular expressions [aren't supported](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9240) in DataFrame.query as well